# Cumulative values within a list

Tags: python, numpy

So if I have a list:

```
list_a = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

And I would like to and the first number to the second number, create a value, then add that to the third and so on:

```
cum_list_a = np.array([2, 6, 12, 20)]
```

How can I achieve that simply? THANKS!

Comment: Did you try googling [`numpy cumulative sum`](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+cumulative+sum)? The solution comes up immediately.

Comment: Also, that's not a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list_a.cumsum()
array([ 2,  6, 12, 20])
```